# How to make a area chart graph in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-area-chart

my data is like:
         city    male     female     total   date
         *abc      1000      2000        3000    2015.1.1

         abc      2000      2500        4500    2015.2.1

         xyz      1000      1000        2000    2015.1.1

         xyz      2000      1000        3000    2015.2.1*

I want to make a area chart that looks like this:

[image]

I am new to tableau, i am not sure the three measures(male, female, total) can do this.

Comment: With very few exceptions, wouldn't male and female suffice for an area chart? Since the values are stacked, you don't need a separate total.

Comment: Do you want a separate area chart for each city? or do you want them combined in some way?